# I am not able to make a React hooks toggle button to change between celcius and farenheit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, openweathermap, use-state

I want to toggle between Celcius and Fahrenheit with an onClick button on °C which can convert to Fahrenheit for my main.temp value max_temp and min_temp at the same time.

Weather.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Homepage from './Homepage';

function Weather() {
  const API_KEY = 'b78ffacf63ad995ef34f6811b0e06433';
  const [localweather, setLocalweather] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  //geolocation to get the local weather
  const getLonLat = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const lon = position.coords.longitude;
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            setLocalweather(result)
            return;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      })
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getLonLat();
  }, [])

  //give input to get other location weather
  const searchInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${query}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        setLocalweather(result)
        setQuery("")
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  return (
    <Homepage
      localweather={localweather}
      getLonLat={getLonLat}
      searchInput={searchInput}
      setQuery={setQuery} />
  )

}
export default Weather;
```

Homepage.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Homepage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.localweather.main && props.localweather.main.temp} °C</h3>
      <span>{props.localweather.main && props.localweather.main.temp_min} °C</span>
      <span>{props.localweather.main && props.localweather.main.temp_max} °C</span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Homepage;
```

I tried to put `props.localweather.main && props.localweather.main.temp` on a `usestate()` but it gives `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your response from your API call is not an array, it will be an object. Also because the API call is asynchronous your `localweather` state won't have those properties **immediately** what you are looking for, that's why you got `undefined` error. Common practice to check for empty values with `&&` in your **render** and not at `useState` to eliminate this issue.

First you need to change from `[]` to empty initial value `{}` in your `useState` as:

```
const [localweather, setLocalweather] = useState({});
```

Then you can have a `null` or `undefined` check as:

```
return (
   { 
      props.localweather &&
      props.localweather.main &&
        <div>
            <h3>{props.localweather.main.temp} °C</h3>
            <span>{props.localweather.main.temp_min} °C</span>
            <span>{props.localweather.main.temp_max} °C</span>
        </div>
   }
)
```

Comment: I got the right value but I am not able to create the toggle button